# Keycloak Authentication Flow NodeJS

Tags: keycloak

I wish to create a custom Keycloak Authentication flow only using JavaScript based technologies.

The logic of Flow is very simple, It will just create two random 4 digit OTP and sent to SMS and Email and in next step it will validate it.

Is this really possible to do it only using nodejs?

Any help or reference materials is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need `Authentication SPI` (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi) which you can develop only in the Java. So, no NodeJS.